# Android, memory leakage through what? Context? Listview? SDK?

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I'm still a beginner in Java and Android.

Recently I came accross a youtube video suggesting to avoid using 'this' when context is asked as a parameter. (: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gz7acZGaXoc&list=PLfuE3hOAeWhYlesGCkCU7xa4_SIfpLCgT&index=4)

And... it all seemed good, and reasonable. But, I'm not quite sure.

I started learning through courses of Udacity and they (as far as I've got) always used 'this' as a keyword for getting the current context. For example:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numberList);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

And this would seem reasonable too. Since, when you are in an activity you would not nessecarily want to grasp the context of the application.

As I understand, Java's garbagecollector wouldn't catch whatever is being referenced and, when (from the first youtuber) you turn your screen - create a new instance - a new activity is actually started without collecting the old. Leading to leakage.

/*getApplicationContext() probably wouldn't be a good choice for running a ListView but for the sake of experimenting and having an other test-case...*/

So, I started out an experiment without turning the screen, yet... instead I would just open a/the new activity through an explicit intent, return, redo, return, redo, etc.. Meanwhile I would run ADB and look at the memory usage.

Both cases would seem to leak a little bit (climbing up 1MB after +/-10 clicks). It would increase in a wave-like fashion: start (at y), opening (jump to x), back (jump to y+1), opening (jump to x+1), back (jump to y+1+1), etc.

So I wanted to ask: is this due to the use of context being partially re-used? Or is there something else in play here? But before that, I decided to go back to the complete basics, remove some of the code and just only explicitly open a new activity, go back, open, etc... Same result.

Now to test a bit further, I brought the app to the background by pressing home, re-opening it again, bringing back to the background, etc... Here too, same restults.

Eventually I ended up with the question: Is this normal? Or... to be more precies. Why does the monitor says it leaks a small amount of memory? *It can also be not a leakage in the application but in the part of the contract it made to monitor this?*
And, if, in the case it actually does leak why? *Is it part of the collector, and should we live with it?.*

Side note my phone runs a SDK < 25.

Rest of the code: Main:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView NumbersList = (TextView) findViewById(numbers);
        NumbersList.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
                startActivity(numbersIntent);
            }
        });
```

Rest of the code: Activity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I came accross a youtube video suggesting to avoid using 'this' when context is asked as a parameter

Hopefully, that is not what they said, as that would be bad advice.

> As I understand, Java's garbagecollector wouldn't catch whatever is being referenced and, when (from the first youtuber) you turn your screen - create a new instance - a new activity is actually started without collecting the old. Leading to leakage.

Using the `Activity` instance for an `ArrayAdapter` does not create a memory leak.

> Both cases would seem to leak a little bit

Both cases *consume* a bit more memory. That does not imply a leak. Bear in mind that the Android garbage collector is not particularly aggressive. Just because you rotate the screen does not mean that every bit of garbage will be collected immediately.

> Why does the monitor says it leaks a small amount of memory?

It doesn't. It says that you are consuming a small amount of additional memory.

The documentation covers [generating heap dumps](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#capture-heap-dump), which is one way to detect leaks. For detecting leaked activities, you could also integrate [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) into your app.